# Where can I get my private Obfs4 bridge?

Tags: bridge, ubuntu, obfs4, vps

I made a private Obfs4 bridge on my Ubuntu with openVZ on a VPS successfully recently, but I have no idea that what's my bridge and how to find it. I need help, please!